# How to find the count of image tags left and right to clicked item?

Tags: jquery

Let say I have 4 images in a form:

```
<form>
<img class="image" src="/imge1.jpg"/>
<img class="image" src="/imge2.jpg"/>
<img class="image" src="/imge3.jpg"/>
<img class="image" src="/imge4.jpg"/>
</form>
```

If I click 1 images is it possible to know the count of images right to the clicked image and count of images left to clicked image?

For example if I clicked image 2, I should get left=1 right=2
for image 3 right=1 left=2.

Comment: No tried?.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with prevAll() and nextAll() for the clicked element as shown in the snippet.

```js
$(".image").on("click", function(e){
  console.log("Left: " + $(this).prevAll("img").length);
  console.log("Right: " + $(this).nextAll("img").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>Whats this? A parapgraph?!</p>
  <img class="image" src="/imge1.jpg"/>
  <img class="image" src="/imge2.jpg"/>
  <img class="image" src="/imge3.jpg"/>
  <img class="image" src="/imge4.jpg"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Instead of using CodePen examples, create a live fiddle inside your awnser.

Comment: just think i have a p tag inside form. then nextall and previousall will fail ryt?

Comment: I just edited the snippet. Try it again. Basically, you can use the selector in prevAll and nextAll functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply combine the use of `.index()` and the length of the parent's `img` children :

`$(this).index()` will give you the number of `img` to the left of the one clicked.

`$(this).parent().children('img').length - $(this).index() - 1` will give your the number of `img` to the right of the one clicked.

```js
$('img').on('click',function(){
  console.log('There are '+($(this).index())+' cat(s) to the left');
  console.log('There are '+($(this).parent().children('img').length - $(this).index() - 1)+' cat(s) to the right');
});
```

```css
img{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <img class="image" src="http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/A-fluffy-cat-looking-funny-surprised-or-concerned.jpg" />
  <img class="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Cat03.jpg" />
  <img class="image" src="http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/small-kitten-meowing.jpg" />
  <img class="image" src="https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/petmd-cat-happy.jpg" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery prevAll(); and nextAll();

```
    $('.image').click(function){
    console.log($.prevAll('.image').length);
    console.log($.nextAll('.image').length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check,

```js
$('.image').click(function(){
var left = $(this).prevAll().length -1;
var right = $(this).nextAll().length -2;
alert("On your left : " + left + "  on your right: " + right);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="image" src="/imge1.jpg"/>
<img class="image" src="/imge2.jpg"/>
<img class="image" src="/imge3.jpg"/>
<img class="image" src="/imge4.jpg"/>
```